# Using RSuite's Tree, Data Is Rendering & Populating But Not Expanding On Default

Tags: reactjs, rsuite

I am using [Rsuite's Tree Component](https://rsuitejs.com/components/tree/) to render data being passed as an array, which I then structure to be a tree. The tree should be fully expanded on load so that the user has an intuitive understanding of the data.

I have a main page and a component called GoalTree, which takes in the state loaded by the main page and passes in a list of goals, which is then structured in the component.

[On Page Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asV6c.png)
[When clicking on the component to expand the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkUaj.png)

From my screengrabs, we can see that the component has the data assembled correctly, and renders the data. But it does not default to being expanded.

Main Page:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {createPath, useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
// import CopyButton from '../../components/buttons/CopyButton';
import { Form, ButtonToolbar, Button, RadioTile, RadioTileGroup } from 'rsuite';
import { Icon } from '@rsuite/icons';
import PlusIcon from '@rsuite/icons/Plus';
import TrendIcon from '@rsuite/icons/Trend';
import DragableIcon from '@rsuite/icons/Dragable';
import GoalTree from "./GoalTree";

function buildCopyUrl(goalId, endpoint){
    return `localhost:3000/${goalId}/${endpoint}`;
}

function ControlBoardPage() {

    const { ancestorId, goalId } = useParams();

    const [phaseIndex, setPhaseIndex] = useState(0);

    const [goals, setGoals] = useState([]);
    const [selectionIndex, setSelectionIndex] = useState(-1);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/ControlBoardPage/getPageData', { params: { "goalId": goalId } });
            setGoals(data);
        }
        fetchData();


    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h3>Control Board</h3>
            <Form layout="horizontal">
                <Form.Group>
                    <GoalTree rawGoals={goals}/>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}

export default ControlBoardPage;
```

GoalTree Component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Tree } from 'rsuite';

function GoalTree(props){
    const { rawGoals } = props;

    let refinedGoals = [...rawGoals];
    refinedGoals.forEach((row) => {
        row['children'] = [];
        row['value'] = row.id;
        row['label'] = row.goal;
    })

    while(refinedGoals.length > 1){
        const childGoal = refinedGoals.pop();

        for(let i = 0; i < refinedGoals.length; i++){
            const isChild = refinedGoals[i].children_ids.includes(childGoal.id);
            if(isChild){
                refinedGoals[i].children.push(childGoal);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <Tree data={refinedGoals} defaultExpandAll={true}/>
    )
}

export default GoalTree;
```

I've tried running through it with the debugger, where nothing looked incorrect.

I've asked on r/learnprogramming, discord servers, and even paid for ChatGPT4 to see if the advanced model could find a solution. No dice, all solutions provided have resulted in the same issue that is currently being presented. Would love to find out what I'm doing wrong here.